# python creating sqlite word dictionary

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to create a database of english words, But no values are being put into the database ,

I am reading each word from a file and using it's sha256 hash to represent the definition of the word, But  when i execute the script the database stays the same and is not being filled with the words, the size of the database also stays the same.

Why is the database not being filled with the values?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sqlite3 as lite
import sys
import hashlib


word_file = open("words.txt", "r")

con = lite.connect('words.db')
cur = con.cursor()  

cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS words(word TEXT PRIMARY KEY, definition  TEXT);")

for word in word_file.read().split():
    cur.execute("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO words VALUES(\"%s\", \"%s\")" % (word, hashlib.sha256(word).hexdigest()))

word_file.close()

# cur.execute("SELECT * FROM words WHERE word = 'hello'")
# print cur.fetchall()
con.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have to `commit` your changes, for your `con`

http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it, the tutorial I was reading did not include that part.